# I want to use Imacro to change all database 'user types' for my company

Tags: imacros

IMACROS: VERSION BUILD=1010 RECORDER=CR  Free version
Windows 10 English
Chrome: Version 90.0.4430.85 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I have close to 7500 'users' in my database. I need to change one, then go to next, etc. I am thinking I need to take the user ID -in the example below that is "7378", and subtract 1 for the next command. I am sure this is easy but I cannot figure it out. Here is what I have that needs to repeat, minus 1, each time:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:7378
TAG POS=7 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Edit
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ACTION:https://xxx.xxx.com/admin/users/7378/edit ATTR=TXT:Change
TAG POS=2 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO ATTR=*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:OK
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Save
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

### Solution for the following FCI:

```
IMACROS: VERSION BUILD=1010 RECORDER=CR 'Free'
Windows 10 English 
Chrome: Version 90.0.4430.85 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

(Will work for all 'Free' Versions, using '!VAR[1-3]', as User Defined Vars are not supported in the 'Free' Versions.)

```
'Set some Start User_ID: (Needs to be +1 from the "real" Start ID.)
SET !VAR1 7379
ADD !VAR1 -{{!LOOP}}

'TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:7378 // (Recorded)
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:{{!VAR1}}
'>
TAG POS=7 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Edit
'>
'TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ACTION:https://xxx.xxx.com/admin/users/7378/edit ATTR=TXT:Change // (Recorded)
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ACTION:https://*/admin/users/{{!VAR1}}/edit ATTR=TXT:Change
'>
TAG POS=2 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO ATTR=*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:OK
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Save
```

... And you can loop that Script 100 times (Max Loop Value for the 'Free' Versions).

... And you'll need to manually edit the `SET !VAR1 7379` to `SET !VAR1 7279` then to `7179` etc before running the next 100 Loops...

---

### Glossary:

- FCI = Full Config Info (=> iMacros + Browser + OS + 'Free'/'PE'/'Trial'/'Pro'/'Enterprise' + all exact Versions.)
- PE = Personal Edition.
- OP = Original Post. // @OP/#OP = Original Poster.
- Qt = Question.

Comment: My "Advice" would be to first run the first Batch 79 times, => for [7378-7300], then for the next Batches, you can specify `7300` => `7200` => `7100` etc as the 'Start ID' and loop the Script 100 times each time...

Comment: this is not working. I cannot figure out how to post the code I am using, however with several hours into trying, and using just as suggested, the latest error I get is: RuntimeError: element BUTTON specified by TXT:Change was not found, line: 12. However I can see the "change" button right there on the page that it stops on.

Comment: Hum, try replacing my `*` with your "real" "www.whatever...", or to completely remove the `FORM` Param...: => `TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Change`... Unless there are several Forms on one same Page (very unusual), the 'FORM' is not really needed for iMacros...